# Pyjq - Remove set of strings defined in a variable

Tags: python, jq

I need to filter some JSON such that only objects with a `www` key that is NOT in the `keysstoremove` array are kept in the final output.

My code:

```
import pyjq, json

keysstoremove = ["KLLIE2D", "FLLIE2D", "SLLIE2D", "ELLIE2D"]
infile = json.load(open('./test.json'))
json_object = pyjq.all('.configurations[] | {www, en_key} | select(.en_key != null)', infile)
```

**Example Output (incorrect):**

```
[{
    "www": "BLLIE2D",
    "en_key": "hashAAAAB3NzaC1y"
},
{
    "www": "KLLIE2D",
    "en_key": "hashAAAAB3NwCXr57"
},
{
    "www": "JLLIE2D",
    "en_key": "hashnAAAt8zlnwg1Pj"
},
{
    "www": "FLLIE2D",
    "en_key": "hashAAAAB3NzaC1ycA"
{
    "www": "ELLIE2D",
    "en_key": "hashAAAAB3Nz0Md9sdvs"
},
{
    "www": "SLLIE2D",
    "en_key": "hashAAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAJ"
}]
```

**Expected output:**

```
[{
    "www": "BLLIE2D",
    "en_key": "hashAAAAB3NzaC1y"
},
{
    "www": "JLLIE2D",
    "en_key": "hashnAAAt8zlnwg1Pj"
}]
```

Comment: It would help if you could provide the contents of `test.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Your jq query does not even mention `keysstoremove`.  One possibility would be to use a jq query such as the following:

```
def keysstoremove:
  ["KLLIE2D", "FLLIE2D", "SLLIE2D", "ELLIE2D"];

.configurations[]
| .en_key as $k
| select( keysstoremove | index($k) | not)
| {www, en_key}
```

### General hint

When experiencing difficulty while using a wrapper such as pyjq, it is often simplest to check that your jq query is correct by using the jq command-line interpreter, which is generally available for the major operating systems.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For some reason i can't get your code work with bash jq. 
where do i define the strings i am supposed to exclude.

Comment: i tried 
cat file.json | jq '.configurations[] | .en_key as $k | select( "KLLIE2D" | index($k) | not) | {www, en_key}'

Comment: The jq filter shown in the answer contains a `def`.

Comment: Thanks very much!